# Iteration over a column in decision table _ODM

Tags: rule-engine, odm, ibm-odm

I have a decision table which looks like :
[image]

and my input to the decision table looks like this :

A = 1, B = 1,4,5 and C =1 .

The requirement is that the decision table processing should halt when the first match is encountered with the decision table . In this case , row number 1 (B =1 ) , it should not check for B=4 and 5.

Please advise how to achieve this logic. I am using ODM 8.9

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to execute just a single row of a decision table is to use specify the *Exit Criteria* in the properties of the rule task in which the decision table appears. If the *Exit Criteria* is set to *Rule Instance*, then only one rule will fire -- after the first rule fires, the rule task will end. If your decision table is the only thing in the rule task then this should give the desired behavior. It would also work if your decision table was the first thing in the rule task to be evaluated, in terms of order and priority.